# What does Smoothness Prior mean in the context of image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I can quote from [an article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6678248&tag=1):

> "The first category of methods, known as diffusion-based inpainting,
>   introduces smoothness priors via parametric models or partial
>   differential equations (PDE) to propagate or diffuse local structures
>   from the exterior to the interior of the hole."

What is Smoothness Prior?

What does this definition mean?

Answer (score 2):

A *prior* is something that you know **a priori** (beforehand) about how the system you're looking at works.

A *smoothness prior* means that you know that the image you're looking at will be smooth in a particular way.

That paper goes on to say:

> The term diffusion comes from the idea of propagating local information with smoothness constraints, by analogy with physical phenomena like heat propagation in physical structures. These phenomena can be formalized with PDEs, and diffusion is therefore performed using PDE-based regularization.

So in this case the smoothness that you know about beforehand is enforced using a partial differential equation.

Comment: How could create a mechanism to mark an answer with the OP no longer a member? I want to answer the question but no one will mark it.

Comment: @Royi No way that I know! Let me do some digging.

Answer (score 0):

"**smoothness prior**" refers to the assumption that the intensity values within an image have a smooth variation, i.e., they change gradually from one pixel to the next. The smoothness prior is used as a constraint in the image inpainting process to fill in the missing pixels with values that are consistent with the surrounding pixels.

In **diffusion-based inpainting** methods, the smoothness prior is introduced via parametric models or partial differential equations (PDEs) that describe the diffusion or propagation of image features from the exterior to the interior of the hole. The idea is to propagate or diffuse information from the known pixels around the hole to the unknown pixels within the hole while maintaining the smoothness constraint.

**For example**, a common diffusion-based inpainting method is the heat equation, which is a PDE that describes the diffusion of heat through a medium. By treating the image as a two-dimensional heat distribution, the heat equation can be used to propagate the intensity values from the known pixels around the hole to the unknown pixels within the hole.

The smoothness prior is enforced by using a diffusion coefficient that depends on the local gradient of the image intensity, such that the diffusion is stronger in regions with high gradients and weaker in regions with low gradients.